# Error while starting GlassFish 2.1

Tags: glassfish

I am using GlassFish 2.1 in my app.

But it  seems that there are some problems with GlassFish start up setting.

I am getting the following error while starting GlassFish.

```
    SEVERE: loader.error_while_loading_app_desc
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/MEjbApp
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.<init>(ApplicationLoader.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.<init>(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.<init>(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.createApplicationLoader(ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.getLoader(ApplicationManager.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)

SEVERE: ERROR while loading application MEjbApp
SEVERE: LDR5006: Failed to load deployment descriptor
com.sun.enterprise.config.ConfigException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/MEjbApp
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.<init>(ApplicationLoader.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.<init>(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.<init>(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.createApplicationLoader(ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.getLoader(ApplicationManager.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/MEjbApp
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:356)
    ... 22 more

SEVERE: core.unexpected_error_occured_while_loading_system_app
javax.management.MBeanException
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.createRootMBean(ApplicationLoader.java:295)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:398)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.management.util.J2EEManagementObjectManager.createAppMBean(J2EEManagementObjectManager.java:547)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.createRootMBean(ApplicationLoader.java:284)
    ... 17 more

SEVERE: loader.error_while_loading_app_desc
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__ejb_container_timer_app
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.<init>(ApplicationLoader.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.<init>(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.<init>(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.createApplicationLoader(ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.getLoader(ApplicationManager.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)

SEVERE: ERROR while loading application __ejb_container_timer_app
SEVERE: LDR5006: Failed to load deployment descriptor
com.sun.enterprise.config.ConfigException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__ejb_container_timer_app
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.<init>(ApplicationLoader.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.<init>(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.<init>(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.createApplicationLoader(ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.getLoader(ApplicationManager.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__ejb_container_timer_app
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:356)
    ... 22 more

SEVERE: core.unexpected_error_occured_while_loading_system_app
javax.management.MBeanException
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.createRootMBean(ApplicationLoader.java:295)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:398)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.management.util.J2EEManagementObjectManager.createAppMBean(J2EEManagementObjectManager.java:547)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.createRootMBean(ApplicationLoader.java:284)
    ... 17 more

SEVERE: loader.error_while_loading_app_desc
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__JWSappclients
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.<init>(ApplicationLoader.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.<init>(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.<init>(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.createApplicationLoader(ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.getLoader(ApplicationManager.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)

SEVERE: ERROR while loading application __JWSappclients
SEVERE: LDR5006: Failed to load deployment descriptor
com.sun.enterprise.config.ConfigException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__JWSappclients
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.<init>(ApplicationLoader.java:112)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.<init>(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ExtendedApplicationLoader.<init>(ExtendedApplicationLoader.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.pluggable.ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.createApplicationLoader(ExtendedApplicationLoaderFactory.java:63)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationManager.getLoader(ApplicationManager.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadOneSystemApp(AbstractManager.java:395)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager$SystemAppStarter.doRun(AbstractManager.java:664)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.runSync(RunnableBase.java:304)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase._submit(RunnableBase.java:176)
    at com.sun.appserv.management.util.misc.RunnableBase.submit(RunnableBase.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractManager.loadSystem(AbstractManager.java:331)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.loadSystemApps(SystemAppLifecycle.java:162)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.SystemAppLifecycle.onStartup(SystemAppLifecycle.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:449)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:409)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:415)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__JWSappclients
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.deploy.shared.FileArchive.open(FileArchive.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.instance.AppsManager.getAppDescriptor(AppsManager.java:356)
    ... 22 more
```

Even When I try to deploy the application, Its not giving any error details OR message like "app deployed successfully".

Can anyone tell me, what is javax.management.MBeanException. And when its generated ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the real problem is this: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps/__JWSappclients`

You can try to fix this by deleting the folder `D:/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/j2ee-apps`. Then you can try if Glassfish starts without errors and redeploy your application. If the error reappears during deployment there is something wrong with your application. You should add some information about your environment to describe the problem in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried by cleaning all the GlassFish cache and I have removed  all the dir from domain1/applications folder and Started the server "without deploying the  app in clean mode".But problem still exist. I am getting the  same error as mentioned above.